# SQL - Combine Two Rows Into One, Based Upon a Derived Value of Both Rows

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I have been given a very complex issue that I may not have the expertise to solve. I have tried a lot of difference methods, but I have not come close to solving this problem.

We have a relational database using SQL Server within an application called Lansweeper. I am working with two tables.  One table (`tblAssets`) houses our computer inventory data, and the other table (`tblRegistry`) houses registry data of these computers.

I have a requirement to query for the computer name , driver name, and driver version all into one row.  However, the driver version and driver name are within two separate registry keys on a computer, and the only way to derive the version and driver is by the registry key value.

I have created a simple query below to start.

```
Select Distinct Top 1000000 tblAssets.AssetName, 
  tblRegistry.Valuename,
  tblRegistry.Value, 
  tblRegistry.Regkey
From tblRegistry
  Inner Join tblAssets On tblAssets.AssetID = tblRegistry.AssetID
Where tblRegistry.Valuename Like '%Driver%'
Order By tblRegistry.Regkey
```

I have provided an image of the current output and the desired output.

[image: Table Format]

I think the biggest road block for me right now is how to treat the value for derived key location values in order to do this.  I have created variants of row_number, pivot and union, but I am really at a loss of what to do.

Comment: not quite sure what you're trying here, but the query you provide has some syntax issues to start with: you should at least include "FROM tblRegistry"

Comment: Hi ollie, sorry for the confusion.  That was a mistake on my part.  The above simple query has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join tblRegistry twice and include the 'Valuename' in the join conditions. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISCTINCT assets.AssetName ComputerName
     , reg1.value Driver
     , reg2.value DriverVersion
  FROM tblAssets assets
  JOIN tblRegistry reg1
    ON reg1.AssetID = assets.AssetID
   AND reg1.Valuename = 'DriverDesc'
  JOIN tblRegistry reg2
    ON reg2.AssetID = assets.AssetID
   AND reg2.Valuename = 'DriverVersion'
```

Comment: Wow, I think that's one of the things we went over in college, and I breezed over it because I didn't see a use for it.... until NOW!
I appended a where clause to that to get the desired result: Where Reg1.Regkey = Reg2.Regkey